# Wrap SVG-DOM element with Snap.svg

Tags: snap.svg

Snap.svg allows to create a Snap-object from SVG-DOM element by CSS selectors.
For example, how to get a Snap-object ***myLine*** wrapping SVG-DOM ***line*** by its ***id***:

```
var paper = Snap('#my-svg');
var myLine = paper.select('#my-line');
```

That's OK.

But what if our SVG-DOM element does not have any ID?

How to create a Snap-object from SVG-DOM element having that element itself?

```
// here I use an ID just to get a variable with the pointer to SVG-DOM element
var svg_dom_element = document.getElementById('my-line'); 

var paper = Snap('#my-svg');
var myLine = paper.select(svg_dom_element); // this line of code throws an error
```

What the third line of code should be here?

*One of the workaround is to assing a random ID to the element and then use paper.select to get a Snap-object. But that is not cool.* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to select it, 'select' will take a css selector, which a DOM element isn't.

All you need to do, is pass Snap the DOM element, so it's even easier :).

```
var myLine = Snap(svg_dom_element);
```

Comment: Is it so simple? I thought Snap(DOM_element) is for initializing the SVG element only. ) Thank you, Ian!